# Why is Apache server being accessed by a host itself?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm facing quite interesting problem.
I have a server with hostname **s1.company.net** and there are many apache virtualhosts.
Time to time is server overloaded and if I check access log a can see thousands of accesses from server itself.
So in a logfile is something like this:
virtualhost.at **s1.company.net** - - [01/Aug/2013:14:13:00 +0200] "GET /page/detail/434-022-1-1 HTTP/1.1" 200 8434 "http://www.google.com" "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
As far as I understand to logging process, that means webserver is accessed from address **s1.company.net** so from a server itself.
Could you please tell me is it normal or not and why?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Turn off `HostnameLookups`. That option should _never_ be enabled.

Comment: Good point! IP address translation could be forged.

Answer (score 4):

Your log lines are not Apache httpd's default, so I would not make too many assumptions about the content of each field. Open Apache's configuration and find the `LogFormat` directive(s). See if `%h` appears anywhere in the format, as this is the foreign host connecting to the server. [Full list of LogFormat variables here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html).

If it is the localhost connecting, you either have a proxy setup somewhere (check for `Proxy` directives in the configuration) or at least one of your sites has been compromised (thinking the former over the latter, but wouldn't make any assumptions at this point). It's also possible another service on the server is acting as a proxy.

Comment: No, it is not default we have custom one: LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"". I checked a config but there are no Proxy directives at all.

Comment: Start checking other software on the server... It might help to turn `HostnameLookups` (httpd.conf directive) off so you can see the IP httpd thinks is accessing the server (might be a name resolution issue and not the server accessing itself).